# ImportError: No module named psycopg2 when running python script from Java

Tags: java, python, psycopg2, scriptengine

I have a python script and I am trying to run it through Java code using this:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

context.setWriter(writer);
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
engine.eval(new FileReader("/Users/folder1/test.py"), context);
```

When I run this code I get error as `javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named psycopg2`. I am doing the import of psycopg2 in my python script.

I already have psycopg2 installed (using `pip install` from the terminal) and when from my terminal I execute `python test.py` it executes but the above java code is failing with the error I have mentioned above.

I have `python 2.7.5` and `psycopg2 2.6.1`. Also I have `CentOS`

What is wrong here and how to resolve it?

**NOTE:** Using `ScriptEngine` to run python script is kind of a requirement for the system. I know there is one `Process` way also to run python script but I cannot use it as the requirements restrict the use of `Process`.

Comment: do you have psycopg2 installed within a context of a virtualenv that your java code doesnt have access to? either that, or this has to do something with psycopg2 not being in the classpath of where the scriptengine runs from....

Comment: @JTurk I installed psycopg2 using pip. How do I check the virtualenv? And how do I check the classpath for scriptengine?

Comment: Very similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33309860/407651. You cannot use psycopg2 from Jython since it is a C extension (as it says at http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html).