# How to check the classpath where Jython ScriptEngine looks for python module?

Tags: java, python, classpath, jython, scriptengine

I have this `Java` code which I am using to run a `python script` using `Jython` `ScriptEngine`:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

context.setWriter(writer);
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
engine.eval(new FileReader("/Users/folder1/test.py"), context);
```

In my `python script` there are several module import statements and when I run the `Java` code I get error as `javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named psycopg2`. All the modules are installed in my machine and when I run the `python script` normally through CLI it executes. So my understanding is that `Jython` `classpath` is looking somewhere else for the `python` modules.

How can I check where does the `Jython` `ScriptEngine` looks for modules and then modify it include where actually my `python` modules are present? I am new to this so please forgive any lack of understanding.

**Note:** I have `CentOS` and `python 2.7.5` installed on my machine

Answer (score 4):

[`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) is a list of strings that specifies where Jython (and Python) searches for modules. You can check its value like so:

```
engine.eval("import sys; print sys.path");
```

To add a directory to `sys.path`, use the [`JYTHONPATH`](http://www.jython.org/docs/using/cmdline.html#jython-launcher-options) environment variable. If `yourmodule` is installed in `/path/to/modules/yourmodule`, it would look like this:

```
export JYTHONPATH=/path/to/modules
```

Another way is to use the [`python.path`](https://wiki.python.org/jython/UserGuide#registry-properties) property.

---

Unfortunately, in  the case of [psycopg2](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html) the above won't help since that package is a C extension and therefore only compatible with CPython. Perhaps you can use the port of Psycopg for Ctypes instead.

Comment: I should write the `export JYTHONPATH` statement in my Java code right? Also is it possible if you could explain a bit about the psycopg2 solution that you suggested? I am new at this so trying grasp the information.

Comment: `JYTHONPATH` is an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). When properly set, its value is recognized by your program. It is not a statement in the Java code.

Comment: Some Python modules don't work in Jython (because they are based on code written in C), and psycopg2 is one of them. It does not matter if `JYTHONPATH`is set. On the psycopg2 installation page that I linked to, it says "there is **an experimental porting of Psycopg for Ctypes**, but it is not as mature as the C implementation yet". So that *might* be solution for you. If you need help with that part of your problem, I suggest that you ask a separate question.

Comment: I apologise again for a bit lack of understanding in me. So do we set the `JYTHONPATH` environment variable in some file or do I just execute the command from CLI?

Comment: `export JYTHONPATH=/path/to/modules` is a bash shell command. If you use another shell, the syntax is a little different. The command can be typed and executed in each shell or it can be put in a config file such as `.bashrc` so that it is automatically run every time you start a new shell. Environment variables can also be defined in an IDE such as Eclipse.

Comment: thanks a lot for suggestions! I have just one additional doubt. Is there any list of some major modules of python which are not compatible with `Jython` for the same reason as `psycopg2`?

Comment: Also this issue of incompatibility will not appear if one uses `Process` approach to execute the python scripts from within Java code right?

Comment: Yes, I guess you could use `Process` or `Runtime` in Java. There are also other options such as [execnet](http://codespeak.net/execnet/). But this is getting off-topic. I have tried to explain how you can find out where Jython looks for modules and how to add to the search path. If you need help with calling psycopg2 from Jython (or finding a replacement for it), please ask a new question.

Comment: I am not aware of any comprehensive list of major modules that don't work in Jython, In general, if a Python module/package uses C extensions, it cannot be used in Jython. A few examples are NumPy, SciPy, lxml.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to add path to folder with custom python libs using ScriptEngine:

```
engine.eval("import sys; sys.path.append(\"/some/path/to/folder/withpylibs\")");
```