# call python script and use external python packages in java

Tags: java, python, intellij-idea, jython, scriptengine

I am trying to run a python script using Java in IntelliJ as shown below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ScriptException, IOException {

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(); //ouput will be stored here

    ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptContext context = new SimpleScriptContext();

    context.setWriter(writer); //configures output redirection
    ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("python");
    engine.eval(new FileReader("test.py"), context);
    System.out.println(writer.toString()); 
}
```

and in my test.py, the error occurred when I try to

```
from suds import WebFault
```

I am wondering how I can install and use this project called suds programmatrically in my code. I have looked around but was not able to find anything related to this.

Project site:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/suds-jurko/0.4.1.jurko.5

Thank you.

Comment: Isolate the problem, does running test.py work without the java launcher?

Comment: @muzzlator on the commandline, I need to run pip install suds_jurko for it to work

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33309860/104891).